# Is this solution for the derivative correct?

Tags: derivatives

Is this solution for the derivative correct? Because I can't get to this answer (provided by the university) no matter what I do:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

I used a double formula, first the product rule then the quotient rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is a mixture of correctly applying rules to slightly incorrect things, not  a calculation mistake.

At the beginning you (numerically correctly) calculate the derivative of the denominator:

$$
\left[ (x^3+2)(x^2-1)\right]' = 5x^4-3x^2+4x.
$$

Then you start to  calculate the derivative of a quotient, using the $(\frac{u}{v})'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$ rule:

$$
\left[\frac{5x^4-3x^2+4x}{x^2+1}\right]'= \ldots
$$

by correctly setting $u=5x^4-3x^2+4x$ and $v=x^2+1$. But that wasn't the task you were given!

The task you were given was to calculate the derivative of

$$
\frac{(x^3+2)(x^2-1)}{x^2+1}
$$

Now my explanation of what I assume went wrong:

1) You correctly found that you need to apply the rule for derivative of quotient of functions.

2) You realized that for that you need the derivative of the denominator.

3) You calculated that derivative: $5x^4-3x^2+4x$:

4) You got lost/confused where exactly you where in the process of solving your task, so you started to solve a 'new' problem: Find the derivative of $\frac{5x^4-3x^2+4x}{x^2+1}$

5) You correctly started to solve this new problem: Setting $u=5x^4-3x^2+4x$ and $v=x^2+1$, find $u'$ and $v'$ and apply the quotient rule.

6) You did all this, then made a 'simple' calculation mistake on one term when expanding $(20x^3-6x+4)(x^2+1)$ (hint: $-6x^3$ only appears once)

So to get on the right track, just apply the knowledge that you have to the 'right' problem and you seem good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to follow what you're doing because it's all just a blur of formulas without text. You should try to explain exactly what you're trying to do and how you're going to do it. This will improve readability. Like this, I'm barely able to follow your first step.

That being said, it looks like you differentiated the numerator twice.

Comment: Yes. I tried it again and I got the solution.

Comment: It is worth noting that the quotient rule is just a combination of the chain and product rule. If you have trouble with it, just keep yourself to using the chain and product rule alone. It'll be just as fast.

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer correct. Next time I will ask a question I will fully write the exercise.

Comment: @JO If this answer solved your problem, you can "accept" it by clicking the little tick to the left of the answer; this will give both you an the answerer a rating boost and it will remove the question from the unanswered list. Cheers.